# Make Emacs load .bashrc / .bash_profile when started by GUI

Tags: bash, emacs

I wrote `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` both in `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`.

However, if I started emacs in terminal using `emacs`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is shown in `getenv`.
If I started it using GUI (installed from apt-get), there is no such variable.

I am on ubuntu 20.04. How could I make GUI started emacs have the same env vars as terminal started one?

Comment: I wonder if meads is being started in a snap or as a systemd —user unit?

Comment: Have you figured this out?

Answer (score 0):

Since Ubuntu 9.04, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` cannot be set in `$HOME/.profile`, `/etc/profile`, or `/etc/environment`. Instead, you need to create a file in the directory `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` that contains the paths where the system should look for shared libraries.

Example: Replace `/path/to/libraries/` with your desired path and execute the following command as root to put the path in the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/emacs.conf` file:

```
echo "/path/to/libraries/" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/emacs.conf
```

More details can be found in the following links:

- Environment variables: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2BAC8-etc.2BAC8-environment
- Launchpad bug #366728: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/366728